# How do I enforce explicit urls via routes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I have a User model, and a UsersController; they look like this:

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public string UsernName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    User[] users = new User[]
    {
        new User { UsernName = "SomeUser123" }
    };

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return users;
    }
}
```

My routes are setup like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

What I am expecting is that I can only access my GetAllUsers() via this url:

```
api/users/GetAllUsers
```

Instead, I am finding that I can additionally access this method via:

```
api/users/
```

How do I enforce that the API is accessed only by using the full path to the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution. It turns out that the RouteConfig class created by Visual Studio using the Web API template was not the only place routing information existed. [This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) lead me to the WebApiConfig class where I changed:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

To

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```